# Unable to compile any C++ Code

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-12.04

Whenever I try to compile a C++ file with IOStream ,  I get this error.. I've tried reinstalling GCC G++ (both 4.6 and 4.9) AND cpp.. It hasnt helped (or maybe I didnt do it the right way). How do I fix this error

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/localefwd.h:40:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:41,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
             from Integration_Any.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/c++locale.h:52:23: error:‘uselocale’was         not declared in this scope
   extern "C" __typeof(uselocale) __uselocale;
                   ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/c++locale.h:52:45: error: invalid type in    declaration before ‘;’ token
   extern "C" __typeof(uselocale) __uselocale;
                                         ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/c++locale.h: In function ‘int     std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)’:       /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/c++locale.h:75:53: error:     ‘__gnu_cxx::__uselocale’ cannot be used as a function
     __c_locale __old = __gnu_cxx::__uselocale(__cloc);
                                                 ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/c++locale.h:100:33: error:     ‘__gnu_cxx::__uselocale’ cannot be used as a function
     __gnu_cxx::__uselocale(__old);
                             ^
```

Comment: Show us your compile statement...!  i.e. `g++ x y z...`

Comment: mpic++ -o Int_Any Integration_Any.cpp -lm (using MPI with math header file)

Comment: This definitely looks like there is something wrong with your installation. Can you provide some details of what environment you are using? Can you try to uninstall and reinstall again and describe what commands you used to do that?

Comment: try creating a script - name it `g++` in a directory you add to the front of your `PATH`, that when called prints out its arguments; then with a little luck you'll be able to see what `mpic++` is actually doing to compile, and you can tell us....

Comment: mpic++ or g++ - both give the same error...

Comment: do you have mpi 64 bits?

Comment: yes - it was working fine before..

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when I build GCC on RHEL5 and then run it on RHEL7.

The underlying cause is the `fixincludes` mechanism in the GCC build. This copies (and modifies) various headers from `/usr/include` on the build system to `<prefix>/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/<version>/include-fixed/`. Some of these headers from RHEL5 cause compilation errors on RHEL7, even after they are "fixed" by `fixincludes`.

My solution is simply to remove these headers from the `include-fixed` directory:

```
features.h
pthread.h
wchar.h
sys/stat.h
bits/string2.h
```

With these removed, my compilation errors disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error using openmpi and a newer version of g++.
You probably are using an mpi installation compiled with another C++ compiler. Compare output of mpicxx -v and g++ -v. I guess mpicxx -v will display an older g++ version, than you have and reinstall your mpi with the newer g++ version you are using.